# Run-time Design

Tags: vb.net, runtime

I'm newbie in vb.net and I just have something to ask you.
I want to create a simple program and I'm trying to do this with run-time design.

[image]

with this form, when you click on the button1 with the caption(Text) "Show Another Form", another form will be created with this code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim NewForm As New Form
        Dim btnCancel As New Button

        NewForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
        NewForm.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
        NewForm.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke
        NewForm.Size = New Size(400, 200)
        NewForm.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Sizable


        btnCancel.Text = "Cancel"
        btnCancel.Size = New Size(150, 50)
        btnCancel.Location = New Point(50, 50)

        NewForm.Controls.Add(btnCancel)
        NewForm.ShowDialog()

        AddHandler btnCancel.Click, AddressOf CancelClick
    End Sub

    Public Sub cancelclick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim x As String = MessageBox.Show("Exit", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        If x = vbYes Then End
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image]

How can I exit the form I've created when you click on the Cancel Button. The code I've provided doesn't work. Pls help me out. Thanks

Comment: I tried to replace the `EventArgs` with `MouseEventArgs` but still, it doesn't work.

Comment: *"The code I've provided doesn't work."* - it's always a good idea to also describe in what way it didn't work, and it what way you expected it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try attach handler code before show dialog

> NewForm.Controls.Add(btnCancel)
>   AddHandler btnCancel.Click, AddressOf CancelClick
>   NewForm.ShowDialog()

Comment: ...thanks man. It worked! Can you tell me what's the AddHandler and AddressOf? I'v been trying to google the answer but I couldn't find one.

Comment: @aerohn AddHandler is used for attach any event and AddressOf for function which will be called when attched event raised.

Answer (score 0):

In your code change the `AddressOf CancelClick`  to `AddressOf cancelclick`

EDIT:

Change the NewForm.ShowDialog() to NewForm.Show() and also change the code as below code then definitely it will work.

```
    Public NewForm As Form
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        NewForm = New Form
        Dim btnCancel As New Button

        NewForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
        NewForm.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
        NewForm.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke
        NewForm.Size = New Size(400, 200)
        NewForm.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Sizable


        btnCancel.Text = "Cancel"
        btnCancel.Size = New Size(150, 50)
        btnCancel.Location = New Point(50, 50)

        NewForm.Controls.Add(btnCancel)
       AddHandler btnCancel.Click, AddressOf cancelclick

        NewForm.Show()

     End Sub

    Public Sub cancelclick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim x As String = MessageBox.Show("Exit", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        If x = vbYes Then End 
    End Sub
```

Comment: I want to show up the form modaly that's why I set it to `.ShowDialog()` :))